# ClassNotFoundException while passing a Serializable

Tags: android, serialization, bundle

I am an Android developer and I am trying to send a `Serializable` object to another `Activity` using a `Bundle`. However, I get the following - `Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object` as an error.

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Below is the code snippet:

```
Bundle previousData = new Bundle();
previousData.putSerializable("GetVehicleInfo_AllTrims", trimsObj);// trimObj is a serialized object
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(androidScrolbleTabbar.TABBAR_PUSHVIEW);
detailsIntent.putExtras(previousData);
detailsIntent.putExtra("ActivityIdentifier", ManualScreenNav2.viewIdentifier);
detailsIntent.putExtra("className", ManualScreenNav2.class.getName());
sendBroadcast(detailsIntent);
```

Below is the full stack trace:

```
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.mobyfactory.pushview (has extras) } in com.adplotmanagement.androidScrolbleTabbar$PUSHViewBroadcastReceiver@461bc340
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:942)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.halcyon.ui.redbumper.entities.RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:1951)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1822)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2008)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1034)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at com.adplotmanagement.androidScrolbleTabbar$PUSHViewBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(androidScrolbleTabbar.java:560)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:910)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    ... 9 more
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.halcyon.ui.redbumper.entities.RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:235)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2590)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:826)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2066)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:1945)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    ... 15 more
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.halcyon.ui.redbumper.entities.RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    ... 25 more
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.halcyon.ui.redbumper.entities.RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.adplotmanagement-1.apk]
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-19 15:39:02.549: E/AndroidRuntime(27084):    ... 25 more
```

Missed adding one more point, I have two applications with same functionality and each app having the same class `GetVehicleInfo_AllTrims` and it is a pojo class. When i run one app in foreground the other app that lives in background is crashing with the above error.

Comment: post your code snippet + full error stack trace here.

Comment: Is your class `RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims` also serializable?

Comment: Yes The class is a serializable class and i have created object(trimsObj) for that class and sending it to another activity.

Comment: can you add the code when you try to receive the broadcast intent and read the serializable? and also post RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims class

Comment: I realize that this isn't an answer: Instead of fixing the problem you describe, you might look into making your object Parcelable.  Using Serializable is a pretty expensive way to go about passing things between Activities.

Comment: RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims class is a simple POJO class and how can i add this class to the application's classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi find the root cause of the issue and resolved it .

In two apps we are using same BroadCastReceivers and its intent filters. Due to this issue the runtime not able to find the appropriate receiver for the app.

I modified the intent filters for two apps differently and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.halcyon.ui.redbumper.entities.RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims
```

> What is the cause of this

The cause of this is exception that the class `com.halcyon.ui.redbumper.entities.RBGetVehicleInfoByVin_AllTrims` was not found.

> how can I fix it?

Make that class available on the application's CLASSPATH.

Comment: Hi EJP, Can you provide me some sample code or links that explains how can i add this class to application's CLASSPATH